# Java class editor like eclipse viewer

Tags: java, eclipse, class, decompiling

I decompiled a Java .jar file, after editing the problem i'm having with it, its not compiling again. So, i had to opt-in to using 7-zip to just bring out the class file and, now i've used 5 different Class Editors, all can't show me the codes like i can understand...

I used `CE(Classeditor.sourceforege.net)`, `dirtyjoe`, `javaeditor(javaeditor.org)`, `Jad` and JD-`GUi`(Seems not to do its work at all)

I imported the `.jar` file into Eclipse as a *Project Reference Library* and the most painful thing is i can see all of the class codes, but i can't edit it...It won't edit. But, it can run.
What can i do to Eclipse to be able to make it  allow editing the `.class` files attached to it.

**EDIT:** I want A Class Editor That Shows in Codes Format, not bytecodes.
I have the source as well in .java format.

This Example is Eclipse Class Viewer(I want same, but not only viewer).

[Eclipse Class Viewer Image, I want something similar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYZqt.png)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? It's not clear at all from your question.

Comment: I am looking for a Class Editor that will be Viewable in Code Format, not Bytecodes...

Comment: JADclipse works for me, not sure what problem you are getting while using JAD.

Comment: I can't see how JadClipse changed anything on my Eclipse after installing it

Comment: @RaviNikam Where do i see the Jadclipse ?

Comment: Please ignore... I missed edit thing here.

Comment: @RaviNikam Your Suggestion is working well for me..
I followed that tutorial, it made JadClipse replace the default decompiler and text editor.. 
I'm still looking for a way to get the .java back into the jar file..

Comment: Oh well, thats great! here is the link just in case if somebody come looking for it. https://5thcross.wordpress.com/2009/05/20/installing-jadclipse-in-eclipse/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to be able to edit class files directly. The Eclipse class viewer only works because it finds (in your project folder or online) a source code version of the jar that you're viewing. It's not actually looking at the class files and decompiling them, AFAIK. So, if you can view the source in Eclipse, your best bet may be to find the source version of the jar (on your machine or on maven, possibly, if you're using maven), and then edit it and build it yourself according to that project's build instructions. How hard that is depends on the library.

As far as being able to decompile, edit, and recompile, I'm not sure. I know that decompilers are not foolproof, and I've only used them as a last-ditch, read-only tool. It seems like it should work both ways, but I wouldn't be surprised to hear it doesn't.

Comment: It is a Maven Compiled project(I mean It uses many packages from maven rep), I don't know how to compile using maven(My reason for not Starting from scratch). I'm only a C/C++ programmer with PHP/MQL language knowledge. I don't know much java and installations on WIndows.

Comment: Its a URL downloader(Not Public) called dataserver.jar and dataclient.jar, So i'm trying to edit the dataclient.jar

Comment: I'm assuming this is built by another team in your organization? I think your best bet is to try and get the source code from the other team or from their version control, or find another way to do whatever you're trying to do.

Comment: But you can view the source code in the Eclipse class viewer? That means it's getting it from somewhere. From maven or from your machine.

Comment: So the problem is when you edit it and compile it, it doesn't work?

Comment: Yes...
It won't compile... So, i tried using 7-zip which won't need to pack anything, it would just update the file(That is working fine), but now i have the .class file. I don't see what to do with it..
I'm confused by javajavajava stuffs and installations(I can't do maven installtion from fresh. I don't know how even though i read the How-to

Comment: I think you will have to install maven or use the Eclipse built-in maven and create a new project for that jar and compile it from scratch. What happens when you do a `mvn --version`?

Comment: I"m not sure if you can swap out a class file in a jar or not. Maybe. Idk.

Comment: Where do i do  --mvn??

Comment: `mvn --version` doesn't matter where.  Sorry, I'm not sure I can help you do all the set up required to build a Java project here in the comments. Maybe a team lead or someone on the team who built the jar could help?

Comment: This isn't a project, Its a completed edition.. I only need to replace the edited class.
I'm sorry if i'm asking too much

Comment: I just don't know how to do what you're trying to do. If it was me I would try to setup and rebuild the whole jar if I had the source code.

Comment: I checked the Mavin version in Eclipse About..
It is 1.6.0**